# BeanWriter not working - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, hippocms

I was adding a field to an existing document type. No error in the CMS web user interface.

The full stacktrace is as follows:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [REST] in context with path [/essentials] threw exception
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:239)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:213)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:131)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.invoke(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.handleRequest(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.doGet(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:242)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 32 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.services.contenttype.HippoContentTypeService.<init>(HippoContentTypeService.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.services.ContentBeansService.getProjectContentTypes(ContentBeansService.java:242)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.services.ContentBeansService.getContentBeans(ContentBeansService.java:218)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.services.ContentBeansService.<init>(ContentBeansService.java:102)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.beanwriter.rest.BeanWriterResource.getImageSets(BeanWriterResource.java:119)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 37 more
```

In the same log, there is also another error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 04.06.2015 09:26:09 ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-9 [GlobalUtils.createSession:234] Error creating repository connection
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] javax.jcr.LoginException: Wrong username or password.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1493)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.impl.RepositoryDecorator.login(RepositoryDecorator.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.HippoRepositoryImpl.login(HippoRepositoryImpl.java:109)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.HippoRepositoryImpl.login(HippoRepositoryImpl.java:98)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.utils.GlobalUtils.createSession(GlobalUtils.java:232)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.ctx.DefaultPluginContext.createSession(DefaultPluginContext.java:114)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.dashboard.utils.CndUtils.getNodeTypesOfType(CndUtils.java:315)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.plugins.gallery.GalleryPluginResource.fetchExisting(GalleryPluginResource.java:352)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:239)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:213)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:131)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.invoke(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.handleRequest(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.doGet(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:242)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Wrong username or password.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.security.UnsuccessfulAuthenticationHandler.handle(UnsuccessfulAuthenticationHandler.java:27)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hippoecm.repository.security.HippoLoginModule.login(HippoLoginModule.java:149)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.LocalAuthContext.login(LocalAuthContext.java:86)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1465)
```

What am I supposed to do about this?

Comment: It seems you get this in the setup application. Did you by any chance, change the default username and password?

Comment: Does changing the password of the default "admin" user counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup application right now only supports local development with admin/admin as the username and password combination. The setup application communicates with the repository, by logging in with the admin/admin combination, so if you have changed the username password combination most actions within the setup application will fail.

Where it goes wrong here is that the setup application is talking to the ContentService API, but fails because the login to the repository is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, @Jeroen, while changing password I am getting, "Password may not be the same as previous 5 passwords. Password must not contain user name, first name or last name", Please help me in that